# UMLDesigner eclipse version neon and luna differences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, eclipse-neon, uml-designer

I have the uml-designer plugin in my eclipse neon with the version 7 of ther uml designer (there's no option to download a previous version), and my co-worker has the version 5. 
Doesn't the version of uml designer that runs in eclipse neon also runs in the eclipse luna? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, the UML Designer 7 version runs on Eclipse Neon. There is lots of bugfixes since the 5 version so, it is better to use the last version.